# Angular protractor load modules

Tags: angularjs, npm, protractor

In own test application I want to use methods for random data generation, for it I use http://chancejs.com/ this library. It contain only one file, but if library contain many files, I want to use it without download manually, only install with `npm install somelib`.  When I run my spec, if library installed with npm, I get errors, that library not found, for example:

```
  //example-spec.js  
  var chance = require('chancejs');
  describe("example", function() {
    it("should be...", function() {
      expcect(chance.phone()).not.toBeNull(); 
    });
  });
```

How to use protractor and import modules from npm?

Answer (score 3):

The docs for chance say that the require statement should be

```
var chance = require('chance');
```

Also, your npm install should probably say `npm install --save-dev chance`.

With those two steps, you should be good.

Comment: it's not work, when i run `protractor test/conf.js` i get `Message:
     Error: Cannot find module 'chance'
`

Answer (score 0):

Check your package.json file. It should be there in the `devDependencies` if you run what Droogans mentioned:

> Also, your npm install should probably say npm install --save-dev chance.

also check

```
then in your app
// Load Chance
var Chance = require('chance');
// Instantiate Chance so it can be used
var chance = new Chance();

// Use Chance here.
var my_random_string = chance.string();
```

check documentation [ChanceJs](http://chancejs.com/)